# Bootstrap boilerplate template for Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9

We are looking for a recommended boilerplate template for Magento 1.x that based on Bootstrap 3\4.

I saw this project but it was updated for M 1.8.x only.

https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate